# Having a drop down list after a certain amount of elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a footer with list in it.Suppose that if the no of elements in list increases more than four, then a drop down list appear for elements which should start at 4th number in the list.That list should contain elements that are after 4th elements  My skills set are only Css html and js. Any ideas? Also can't use glyphicons

Comment: Didn't get your point, please rephrase, make it more clear to understand, visual representation would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
var limit = 2;
var elems = $("#list li").detach();
var select = "";

for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (i < limit) {
        $("#list").html($("#list").html() + (elems[i]).outerHTML);
    }else{
        select += "<option>" + $(elems[i]).text() + "</option>";
    }
}
select = "<select>"  + select + "</select>";
$("#list").html($("#list").html() + select);
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/007kj2a6/)

Change the `limit` variable to change the number of list values to be shown, the rest will be shown in the dropdown.